# MailForm , NameError , uninitialized constant MailForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

So i actually have my site deployed using nginx.
and i wanted to add another function to it which is a contact us page.
So i used this site to guide me.
https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

on localhost it is working fine, however on my domain site itself it kept on getting this error... 
[image: mailform error]

any ideas?

UPDATE:  I gave up , and i did this instead 
https://www.murdo.ch/blog/build-a-contact-form-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1

Answer (score 0):

From what you've provided, it seems that the `mail_form` gem is not installed on your *remote* machine. Make sure `bundle install` command is run on remote machine by you or your deployment script.

Comment: hey, when i did this on my deployment env...
bundle show mail_form
Could not find nokogiri-1.7.1 in any of the sources

Comment: how do i install on my remote machine ? i don't understand sorry, my knowledge is a bit new on these things.
i usually just run bundle install on new gems , and when i first start the project

Comment: You need to ssh into your remote server and run `bundle install` there.